# correctness of a sentence

Tags: sentence

A sentence from an option of a multiple-choice question in ACT English:

> Eventually, snails evolved that would use mucus to build small rafts of air bubbles on which they could float to the surface of the ocean to feed.

Is this a grammatically correct sentence? I feel like there are two predicates: evolved and would use.

Comment: It's fine. There are two predicates because there are two clauses: a matrix (main) clause (the sentence as a whole) and a subordinate relative clause ("that would use mucus to build small rafts of air bubbles on which they could float to the surface of the ocean to feed") modifying "snails".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Eventually, snails evolved that would use mucus to build small rafts*
> *of air bubbles on which they could float to the surface of the ocean*
> to feed.*emphasized text*

It's fine. There are indeed two predicates because there are two clauses: a matrix (main) clause (the sentence as a whole) and a subordinate relative clause ("that would use mucus to build small rafts of air bubbles on which they could float to the surface of the ocean to feed") modifying "snails".

The relative clause is postposed over the verb "evolved", but there is no grammatical error or ambiguity about its antecedent.

Comment: I am glad that you were able to add a grammatical analysis to my rather utilitarian one.

Answer (score 1):

A shortened and grammatically uncontroversial form of such a sentence might be *Eventually, snails that use mucus evolved*.

To put your original sentence into this form with a terminal *evolved* requires the reader to wait a long time for the main verb *evolved*, as in some long German sentences. We are not accustomed to such long waits in English, so it seems reasonable to use your original form instead, regardless of any other consideration.